# Trying to make a recursive call in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

This is my first question here so be kind :-) I'm trying to make a recursive call here, but I get the following compiler error:

```
In file included from hw2.cpp:11:
number.h: In member function ‘std::string Number::get_bin()’:
number.h:60: error: no matching function for call to ‘Number::get_bin(int&)’
number.h:27: note: candidates are: std::string Number::get_bin()

    string get_bin () 
        {
              bin = "";
              printf("Value is %i\n",val);
              if (val > 0)
            {
              int remainder = val;
              printf("remainder is %i\n",remainder);
              printf("numbits is %i\n",size);
              for (int numbits = size-1;numbits>=0;numbits--)
                {
                  //printf("2 raised to the %i is %i\n",numbits,int(pow(2,numbits)));
                  printf("is %i less than or equal to %i\n",int(pow(2,numbits)),remainder);
                  if (int (pow(2,numbits))<=remainder)
                {   


                  bin+="1";
                  remainder -= int(pow(2,numbits));

                  printf("Remainder set to equal %i\n",remainder);
                }
                  else
                {
                  bin+= "0";
                }

                }
              return bin;
            }
              else
            {
              int twoscompliment = val + int(pow(2,size));
              return get_bin(twoscompliment);
            }
```

Any thoughts? I know get_bin works for positive numbers.

Comment: Is this the complete code? there is no `Number` class in the code. In the recusrive call you are making, you are passing an integer argument but there is not function called `get_bin` which takes an integer as argument.

Comment: Whatever the answer to your question, you certainly shouldn't be using floating-point arithmetic here. Perhaps the automatic use of double-precision FP arithmetic means that all values can be held exactly, but that's not something that you should be having to think about in this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last line you are calling `get_bin()` with an integer reference argument, but there are no formal parameters in the function signature.

Comment: Thanks, Wow that was a quick answer.

Comment: The C++ crew here is pretty sharp. I don't usually finish typing before 3 answers arrive :) The other answers have some good additional info over mine.

Answer (score 2):

```
string get_bin ()
return get_bin(twoscompliment);
```

These are mutually incompatible. I don't see how you can say that code works for positive numbers since it's not even compiling.

You probably need to change the first line to something like:

```
string get_bin (int x)
```

but, since you don't actually *use* the argument, you may have other problems.

If you're using global or object-level variables to do this work, recursion is not going to work, since they different levels will be stepping on each other's feet (unless you do your *own* stack).

One of the beauties of recursion is that your code can be small and elegant but using local variables is vital to ensure your data is level-specific.

By way of example, examine the following (badly written) pseudo-code:

```
global product
def factorial (n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    product = factorial (n-1)
    return n * product
```

Now that won't work for `factorial (7)` since `product` will be corrupted by lower levels. However, something like:

```
def factorial (n):
    local product
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    product = factorial (n-1)
    return n * product
```

will work just fine as each level gets its own copy of `product` to play with. Of course:

```
def factorial (n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * factorial (n-1)
```

would be even better.

Comment: I ended up copying the function nested in the if statement and overloading the get_bin method. So it's no longer a recursion because I cant eliminate my global variable as I'm building this to a spec for a class. and we must use a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The function is defined to take no arguments, yet you pass an `int`.

It looks like you're accessing a global or member variable `val`. That should probably be converted into the argument.

```
string get_bin ( int val )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not declared `bin` and `val` in the function I guess they are global.

Now you define the function `get_bin()` to return a string and not accept anything. But in the recursive call you are passing it an `int`. Since you want to pass `twoscompliment` as `val` for the recursive call you can do:

```
int twoscompliment = val + int(pow(2,size));
val = twoscompliment; // assign twoscompliment to val
return get_bin();
```

Comment: I cant have val change because its storing the negative number in decimal, which must be retained. Thanks for the help though, I see what you are saying.